# Some objects don't deform with the others while in pose mode

Tags: mesh, objects, rigging

This is mainly what happens when I try to pose the rig.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgIdf.jpg  (GIF)

Almost all the rig works fine except for these few, even though these few should be in the same group:

> [image]

All of the rig is colored blue in weight paint, no color difference.

As for for the snag in the dress in the gif, I can fix that.

Comment: Please post the animated gif here as well, we try to avoid too many external links if we can.

Comment: You have to manually fix the weights that generated automatically.